# CopiarPegar una columna a otra columna VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Qué tal, tengo un problema copiando la columna G de Libro1 a la columna 0 de Libro 2, estoy tratando de copiar y pegar en la última celda disponible de la columna O y así sucesivamente.

Me despliega la ventana con el error '6' de Desbordamiento

Adjunto mi macro:

```
Private Sub CopiarColumna(Archivo As String)
Dim Lcopia As Workbook
Dim LDestino As Workbook
Dim Destino As Worksheet
'--
Set LDestino = ActiveWorkbook
Set Destino = ActiveSheet
Set Lcopia = Workbooks.Open(Archivo)

Sheets("ReporteCifrasControl").Range("G2" & Sheets(1).Range("G" & Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Cell).Copy
MsgBox ("Ya copié")
Destino.Range("O" & Destino.Range("O" & Cells.Count).End(xlUp).cell + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
MsgBox ("Pero no pego nada")
Destino.Range("O" & Destino.Range("O" & Cells.Count).End(xlUp).cell + 1).PasteSpecial xlFormats
MsgBox ("Sigo sin hacer nada")


ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Qué línea da el error? ¿cuantas filas con datos hay en la hoja REPORTECIFRASCONTROL?

Comment: La de Sheets("ReporteCifrasControl")... pero lo arreglé modificando el rango, y a su vez me había equivocado con lo de lastcell ya que sigue siendo una fila, entonces implementé como encontrar la última fila y cambiar el rango @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Answer (score 1):

Solución que implementé y funciona correctamente:

```
Private Sub CopiarColumna(File As String)

    Dim Lcopy As Workbook
    Dim LDestiny As Workbook
    Dim Destino As Worksheet
    '--
    Set LDestiny = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Destino = ActiveSheet
    Set Lcopy = Workbooks.Open(File)


    Sheets("ReporteCifrasControl").Range("G2:G" & Sheets(1).Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy
MsgBox ("Copied")
Destino.Range("O" & Destino.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
MsgBox ("Dont do anything")


    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End Sub
```

Lo que hice fue cambiar el rango ya que solamente había seleccionado G2 y en vez de tratar de buscar la última celda, el concepto sigue siendo el de una fila, entonces encuentra el último valor disponible de la fila dentro de la columna G y copia los datos seleccionados sucesivamente encontrando el último valor disponible de la fila.